# Network LOOP on Switch with DATA link and Voice Vlan

Tags: networking

I am having a problem with a loop being detected on my network. I have a DATA link from the gateway to a Netgear GS724Tv4 on 192.168.0.0/22 and a VOICE link from the gateway to the Netgear GS724Tv4 on VLAN 869 10.117.22.0/24. The DATA link runs on the default Switch VLAN and is not tagged. The voice VLAN it tagged on all ports on VLAN 869. Everything is working and Voice quality is good, however, I'm getting a Loop detection on a Netgear GS724TPv2 on the port that is connected to the GS724Tv4. So, from what I'm gathering, the loop is on the first switch (GS724Tv4). I suspect that there is a misconfiguration on either the switch or the gateway. What can I do to eliminate the loop?